# Imported bibliography from endnote doesn't show up on pdf viewer

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I'm preparing a document for my thesis and I imported a set of references from endnote (see them below what the references look like). The references document is name 'ProposalRefences.bib' but when calling it with the code I have, it keeps giving an error saying "Empty bibliography on input line 170". Some help would be greatly appreciated, I can't tell if I'm not seeing something.

This is the code I have:

````
```

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[letterpaper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ProposalReferences.bib} % with extension

\newcommand\skiplines[1]{\vspace{#1\baselineskip}}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography


\end{document}
````

```
        

> My references (exported from OneNote)
>Document called "ProposalRefences.bib"

         
      
@book{RN16,
   author = {Boyd, Robert W.},
   title = {Nonlinear optics},
   year = {2020},
   type = {Book}
}

        
@article{RN3,
   author = {Alaoui, Chakib},
   title = {Peltier Thermoelectric Modules Modeling and Evaluation},
   journal = {Chakib Alaoui International Journal of Engineering},
   volume = {5},
   pages = {2011-114},
   year = {2011},
   type = {Journal Article}
}

@article{RN1,
   author = {Arbutina, D. S. and Vasic-Milovanovic, A. I. and Kovacevic, U. D.},
   title = {Probabilistic Analysis of Voltage Divider Ratios},
   journal = {Fme Transactions},
   volume = {47},
   number = {3},
   pages = {624-633},
   ISSN = {1451-2092},
   DOI = {10.5937/fmet1903624A},
   url = {<Go to ISI>://WOS:000465592100027},
   year = {2019},
   type = {Journal Article}
}

@article{RN14,
   author = {Breunig, Ingo},
   title = {Threewave mixing in whispering gallery resonators},
   journal = {Laser and Photonics Reviews},
   volume = {10},
   number = {4},
   pages = {569-587},
   ISSN = {1863-8899 1863-8880},
   year = {2016},
   type = {Journal Article}
}

@article{RN11,
   author = {Darsow-Fromm, Christian and Dekant, Luis and Grebien, Stephan and Schröder, Maik and Schnabel, Roman and Steinlechner, Sebastian},
   title = {NQontrol: An open-source platform for digital control-loops in quantum-optical experiments},
   journal = {Review of Scientific Instruments},
   volume = {91},
   number = {3},
   ISSN = {0034-6748},
   DOI = {10.1063/1.5135873},
   url = {https://doi.org/10.1063/1.5135873},
   year = {2020},
   type = {Journal Article}
}

@article{RN10,
   author = {Darsow-Fromm, Christian and Schröder, Maik and Gurs, Julian and Schnabel, Roman and Steinlechner, Sebastian},
   title = {Highly efficient generation of coherent light at 2128  nm via degenerate optical-parametric oscillation},
   journal = {Optics Letters},
   volume = {45},
   number = {22},
   pages = {6194-6197},
   DOI = {10.1364/OL.405396},
   url = {https://opg.optica.org/ol/abstract.cfm?URI=ol-45-22-6194},
   year = {2020},
   type = {Journal Article}
}

@article{RN5,
   author = {Jovanović, Jelena and Denic, Dragan},
   title = {NTC thermistor nonlinearity compensation using Wheatstone bridge and novel dual-stage single-flash piecewise-linear ADC},
   journal = {Metrology and Measurement Systems},
   volume = {28},
   pages = {523-537},
   DOI = {10.24425/mms.2021.136616},
   year = {2021},
   type = {Journal Article}
}

@article{RN2,
   author = {Nair, Anu and Balakrishnan, P.},
   title = {REVIEW PAPER ON THERMOELECTRIC AIR-CONDITIONER USING PELTIER MODULES},
   journal = {International Journal of Mechanical Engineering},
   volume = {4},
   pages = {49-56},
   year = {2015},
   type = {Journal Article}
}

@article{RN13,
   author = {P. A. Franken, A. E. Hill, C. W. Peters, and G. Weinreich},
   title = {GENERATION OF OPTICAL HARMONICS},
   journal = {Physical Review Letters},
   volume = {7},
   number = {4},
   url = {https://journals.aps.org/prl/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.7.118},
   year = {1961},
   type = {Journal Article}
}

@article{RN4,
   author = {Petkovšek, Marko and Nemec, Mitja and Zajec, Peter},
   title = {Algorithm Execution Time and Accuracy of NTC Thermistor-Based Temperature Measurements in Time-Critical Applications},
   journal = {Mathematics},
   volume = {9},
   number = {18},
   pages = {2266},
   ISSN = {2227-7390},
   url = {https://www.mdpi.com/2227-7390/9/18/2266},
   year = {2021},
   type = {Journal Article}
}

@article{RN6,
   author = {Renna, M. and Ruggeri, A. and Sanzaro, M. and Villa, F. and Zappa, F. and Tosi, A.},
   title = {High Detection Rate Fast-Gated CMOS Single-Photon Avalanche Diode Module},
   journal = {IEEE Photonics Journal},
   volume = {12},
   number = {5},
   pages = {1-12},
   ISSN = {1943-0655},
   DOI = {10.1109/JPHOT.2020.3017092},
   year = {2020},
   type = {Journal Article}
}

@article{RN12,
   author = {Zu, Rui and Wang, Bo and He, Jingyang and Wang, Jian-Jun and Weber, Lincoln and Chen, Long-Qing and Gopalan, Venkatraman},
   title = {Analytical and numerical modeling of optical second harmonic generation in anisotropic crystals using ♯SHAARP package},
   journal = {npj Computational Materials},
   volume = {8},
   number = {1},
   pages = {246},
   ISSN = {2057-3960},
   DOI = {10.1038/s41524-022-00930-4},
   url = {https://doi.org/10.1038/s41524-022-00930-4},
   year = {2022},
   type = {Journal Article}
}

@misc{RN7,
   url = {http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-7766-8-bit-AVR-ATmega16U4-32U4_Datasheet.pdf},
   type = {Online Multimedia}
}

@misc{RN17,
   volume = {41},
   number = {10},
   url = {https://www.proquest.com/openview/4bac2be9c18dc9a052fc171dda451fb6/1?pq-origsite=gscholar&cbl=41118},
   year = {1999},
   type = {Online Multimedia}
}

@misc{RN15,
   url = {https://press.rebus.community/historyoftech/chapter/chapter-15-guest-author-technological-applications-of-the-theory-of-relativity/},
   year = {2021},
   type = {Online Multimedia}
}

@phdthesis{RN8,
   author = {Vardaro, Marco},
   title = {TOWARD A FULLY AUTOMATED AND DIGITALLY CONTROLLED SQUEEZED VACUUM SOURCE FOR GRAVITATIONAL WAVE DETECTORS},
   university = {Università di Padova},
   url = {https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwivx4uOvNWCAxXG2QIHHRavBwkQFnoECBcQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.research.unipd.it%2Fretrieve%2Fe14fb26f-e670-3de1-e053-1705fe0ac030%2FMarco_Vardaro_-_PHD_Thesis_-_2018_01_14.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3wBTHpYGEvx5UU2gJ9g4T0&opi=89978449},
   year = {2018},
   type = {Thesis}
}
```

Comment: you need to cite entries (or to cite all entries with \nocite{*}).

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Ulrike Fischer's comment, you need to use `\nocite{*}` to make citations show up in your bibliography even if you didn't cite them. It's a good shortcut when a paper is still in development.

Note that it must be used in the right place, i.e. within the document

```
…
\begin{document}
…
\nocite{*}
…
\end{document}
```

`\nocite{*}` can be dangerous for a thesis, because it makes you cite papers you didn't *actually* cite.

I'd advise against using it mostly.

Many people (including me) use `.bib`-files as libraries to cite from with the keys they are used to. That way you can have your library in one file for all* papers. It's quite simple and convenient once you're used to it.